# How to enable Firebug alpha on Firefox Nightly?

Tags: firefox-extensions, firebug

I use [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/) and the [alpha release of Firebug 3.0](https://getfirebug.com/firebug3). Until today, I've never had a problem with that Firebug extension. Today, however, when updating Nightly, I was notified that Firebug had been disabled because its author could not be verified. I visited the Firebug website and tried installing the latest release, but loading the xpi file produces the following alert:

[image]

When I click Allow, the installation still does not proceed:

[image]

What can I do to get Firebug back up and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config)
2. Set the preference `xpinstall.signatures.required` to `false` (by double-clicking it)
3. Restart the browser

See http://www.ghacks.net/2015/06/19/how-to-disable-the-firefox-40-add-on-signing-requirement/ for more information.